# MySQL/PHP - query multiple tables to see if records match number in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I have a form with checkboxes that I am grabbing as an array when the form is submitted:

```
<input name='price[]' type='checkbox' value='1'/>
<input name='price[]' type='checkbox' value='2'/>
<input name='price[]' type='checkbox' value='3'/>
<input name='price[]' type='checkbox' value='4'/>
```

I then grab the values in the array and query the DB like this:

```
$priceArray = $_POST['price'];
$selectPrice = join(',',$priceArray);

"SELECT DISTINCT community FROM community_prices WHERE prices IN ($selectPrice)"
```

This works great, but I need to do the same thing with 3 additional arrays and 3 additional tables, and I want to do it all from the same query.

so for instance:

table 1 community_prices has the following fields: id,community,prices

table 2 community_amenities has the following fields: id,community,amenities

table 3 community_demographic has the following fields: id,community,demographic

table 4 community_products has the following fields: id,community,product

Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Answer (score 0):

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) may be your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN to select from multiple table, For example

```
SELECT "YOUR FIELDS" FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 ON  table2.prices IN ($selectPrice)
    JOIN table3 ON  table3.community = table1.comumnity
    JOIN table4 ON  table4.community = table3.comumnity
GROUP BY "YOUR FIELD"
ORDER BY "YOUR FIELD"
```